# Canonical, language-agnostic question for if(var != "x" || var != "y" ...)

Tags: discussion, canonical

At least three times today I've seen questions about the following kind of `if` statement:

```
if (var != "x" || var != "y" || var != "z")
```

The most recent is [Why is my if statement activating when it is not supposed to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311591/why-is-my-if-statement-activating-when-it-is-not-supposed-to). I've seen it in C, JavaScript, PHP, Python, and other languages.

This is one of the most common errors people make in writing `if` statements. The answer is simply to change `||` to `&&`. So there are thousands of duplicates. But when I was trying to find one so I could mark that question as a duplicate, I couldn't; phrases like "if statement" are just too common. I'll bet there's already a really good answer out there, does anyone have a link to one that could serve as the canonical answer?

Actually, the answer posted in the above question explains the issue pretty well. So if no one has a better one to suggest, I'll probably start using that.

There are similar issues with:

```
if (var == "x" || "y" || "z")
```

and

```
if (var != "x" || "y" || "z")
```

There are some languages where this actually works, but in most of the common languages it doesn't do what the programmer intends. Again, if someone has a canonical question for these, please share it.

Comment: The question you linked seems unsuitable as a good reference, and should probably be closed as "simple typographical error". I assume this will apply to all other such questions as well, since someone who is able to distill their problem down to a minimal example should in the process of doing so solve it themselves.

Comment: What are the advantages of closing such questions as duplicates instead of 'too localized because of typo'? Do these questions serve a purpose for future visitors? I'd think most of them get scrubbed.

Comment: The Python dupe for the latter mistake is [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125) I don't see the former nearly as much in Python.

Comment: The very fact that the same problem keeps showing up suggests it is not "too localized".

Comment: Concerning the latter problem: [C#](https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20c%23%20compare%20variable%20against%20multiple%20values) & [Java](https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+compare+variable+against+multiple+values). The first problem (`&&` vs `||`) should be closed as a typo. The latter already has language-specific solutions, they just aren't connected yet.

Comment: What really pisses me off about such questions is that the poster does not consider breaking up the expression into smaller ones with intermediate booleans, (in order to find out which fails).  Debugging 101 - 'spit up the problem area into several smaller ones'.

Comment: Is this a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask?

Comment: @ntoskrnl Not very likely, but we don't actually have a flag for that anymore.

Comment: @HugoRune I don't consider this a typo, it's a basic misunderstanding of how boolean logic works. Newbie programmers try to translate logical expressions from English to PHP/JS/C, but they don't translate directly. They also need to be educated about de Morgan's Law.

Comment: It seems to come up more often in a `while` or `do/while` loop, than it does in an `if` statement.  For example (shamelessly plugging my own answer), there's http://stackoverflow.com/q/22397105 and many others like it.

Answer (score 31):

I'm currently maintaining a list of javascript questions that deal with the `if (var == "x" || "y" || "z")` problem:

```
[129] 13-08-21 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347033/how-to-shorten-my-conditional-statements
[1]   12-02-02 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values
[12]  11-08-18 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values
[9]   12-12-19 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944216/javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-permissible-conditions |>http://stackoverflow.com/a/13944262/1048572
[0]   12-12-19 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959064/javascript-comparing-single-value-against-multiple-values-with-or-operands |>http://stackoverflow.com/a/13959224/1048572
[1]   13-02-25 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066671/optimize-or-in-if
[13]  13-03-11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343484/checking-a-variable-value-using-an-or-operator |> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15343556/1048572
[2]   13-10-09 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561257/combining-multiple-conditions-into-one-in-javascript
[2]   11-04-08 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599957/conditional-if-for-many-values-better-way
[3]   11-10-28 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931118/shorter-way-to-check-multiple-or-conditions
[0]   13-05-25 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751883/concise-way-to-compare-multiple-element-values-in-javascript-jquery
[0]   12-08-06 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836081/javascript-if-statement-used-to-check-file-extensions-not-working
[2]   12-10-05 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743248/how-to-nest-or-statements-in-javascript
[3]   13-01-08 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218565/javascript-formatting-for-if-condition
[0]   13-09-02 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566394/how-do-i-say-if-value-is-not-equal-to-a-b-or-c
[2]   12-10-08 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778196/javascript-if-variable-variable2-variable3
[0]   12-08-27 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146629/eliminating-multiple-or-conditions-in-javascript
[0]   13-04-11 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950685/javascript-if-statement
[3]   14-01-29 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441876/jquery-is-there-a-faster-way-of-writing-or-operator-in-javascript
```

I have **not yet found** a good, canonical, thorough, catch-all answer which explains all ways of solving this in JS, including pros&cons for each (where is it applicable, how fast is it, what browser support does it have, how easy to understand, how concise, …)

**I'm planning to write** one as soon as I find time though, so that we could close them all.

Comment: The upvote count seems to say that I should *take* the time to write that canonical post…

Comment: Are none of these questions really duplicates of each other? Nor of sampathsris' language-agnostic attempt?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel They're not duplicates of sampathsris' canonical, which is about the `var != "x" || var != "y" || var != "z"` problem. The `var == "x" || "y" || "z"` problem is a different one. And I still have neither written a new canonical nor decided upon choosing an existing one - but my private list has grown a bit since (until I stopped some years ago)

Comment: Oh, I got confused because OP was asking about two different situations.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It took me a minute or two as well after coming back to this thread and looking at the other answer :-)

Answer (score 19):

I don't think there can be a language agnostic answer to this question, because some languages allow expressing the concept [item not in a list or set] more precisely.

For instance, I've always thought that one of Pascals advantages over C was its set handling.  In more modern languages, many of them have collections classes, which has a Contains method.  In SQL, you'd use NOT IN as the answer.

How to handle this definitely depends upon the language.

Comment: Good point - every language have its own canonical way of expression "item  (doesn't) belong to set".

Comment: Even if there's a way to specify "value not in set", if it's just 2-3 hard-coded values it's often just as good to spell it out with a few comparisons. And it's educational for them to understand how boolean logic works.

Comment: @Barmar:  a sequence of ANDs or ORs is not going to be considered "educational" for SQL.

Comment: @jmoreno Good point, I wouldn't use this in SQL. But in PHP, I wouldn't write `!in_array($answer, array('y', 'n'))`, it's too convoluted compared to `$answer != 'y' && $answer != 'y'`

Comment: @Barmar: !in_array($answer, ['y','n']) is cleaner, but I probably wouldn't use it, unless it was a common idiom in that code.  But really, that's my point.  You can have a canonical answer for A language at a specific point in time, but not for all languages or even a given language for all time.  The array('y','n') version is less acceptable because it is wordy,  [] is more acceptable because its not as long.  If php added a method to arrays so that it was ['y','n']::contains($answer), I might revisit my opinion, even though it is longer than the is_array version using [].

Comment: We could have a canonical answer that explains the correct logic of the original expression, and also has list of language-specific shorthand forms and idioms. I guess that's not truly "language-agnostic", but my main point was to try to get it all in one place, since there's so much in common across the languages.

Answer (score 9):

I have just (attempted to) create a canonical question/answer pair for the likes of this question: [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26337003/1461424)

The answer is *community wiki*, but I'm not sure how to make the question a community wiki. If the question suits as a canonical example, please feel free to edit and improve.

Comment: I like it. I've bookmarked it and started editing it -- I added a section listing language-specific shortcuts, as I suggested in a comment on @jmoreno's answer.

Comment: FWIW, I suggest you move the meta-commentary to the comments.